# uicollectionViewCell disable "cut" on long tap

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView, all is working fine,
but

the UICollectionViewCell when long tapped shows a "Cut" bubble message,

how to disable this?

i made the

> imageView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

but the cell still showing a "Cut" bubble, how to solve this? thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the delegate's  `collectionView:shouldShowMenuForItemAtIndexPath:` to return NO.

See the docs here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012176-CH1-SW2

Comment: That isn't what I said to do, is it? This is a delegate method. You do not call it. It calls you. You need to _implement_ it so that it _returns_ NO. Read what I said! _Read the documentation that I pointed you to._